# Detailsview Row Height and/or row spacing

Tags: asp.net, css

How can I make a specific detailsview row of a specific height? I tried css and itemstyle-height, but I seem to have misplaced my brain and/or visibly don't understand how some things work in that.

May sound stupid or inappropriate of a use, but I want to use a detailsview to show information about something, and I'm separating information with a "spacer" row for now.

Another suitable answer to my question would be the way to insert space after a specific row to ensure that my sections are separated.

Why doesn't the "itemstyle-height" property of my templatefield isn't obeying my orders? I want it tamed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm personally not offended at all by programmatically adding a separator row that lets you visually break apart the sections of your data.

Even if this requires looping once through your dataset, your performance will be virtually unchanged and the additional separator row will give you a lot of flexibility to style, label, space the sections as necessary.

Comment: Problem is: I have no control whatsoever over the spacer row's height.

Comment: Well... you have an HTML problem on your hands then.  Check out the generated HTML.  Maybe even try copying the entire generated html to a temporary .html file and tweaking it to get the effect you need, then you can take that and try to get ASP.NET to generate the same HTML.  In general, I usually avoid ASP.NETs built in attributes like "itemstyle-height" and instead prefer to add CSS classes or inline styles, like style="height: 30px;" or whatever.